# Regular Expression to match a group of alphanumerics followed by a group of spaces, making a fixed total of characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression using C#/.Net that matches 1-4 alphanumerics followed by spaces, followed by 10 digits.  The catch is the number of spaces plus the number of alphanumerics must equal 4, and the spaces must follow the alphanumerics, not be interspersed.

I'm at a total loss as to how to do this.  I can do `^[A-Za-z\d\s]{1,4}[\d]{10}$`, but that lets the spaces fall anywhere in the first four characters.  Or I could do `^[A-Za-z\d]{1,4}[\s]{0,3}[\d]{10}$` to keep the spaces together, but that would allow more than a total of four characters before the 10 digit number.

Valid:
`A12B1234567890
AB1 1234567890
AB  1234567890`

Invalid:
`AB1  1234567890 (more than 4 characters before the numbers)
A1B1234567890  (less than 4 characters before the numbers)
A1 B1234567890  (space amidst the first 4 characters instead of at the end)`

Comment: Please define your criteria clearly. I am not sure what *that would allow more than a total of four characters before the 10 digit number* means. What if you require at least 1 space? `^[A-Za-z\d]{1,4}\s{1,3}\d{10}$`.

Comment: It would be really helpful to include a set of matches and non-matches

Comment: To be clear, if there are 4 alphanumerics character at the beginning, there is no spaces to be valid, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the check with a look-behind `(?<=^[\p{L}\d\s]{4})` that will ensure there are four allowed characters before the 10-digits number:

```
^[\p{L}\d]{1,4}\s{0,3}(?<=^[\p{L}\d\s]{4})\d{10}$
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cd%5d%7b1%2c4%7d%5cs%7b0%2c3%7d(%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cd%5cs%5d%7b4%7d)%5cd%7b10%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=Valid%3a+%0d%0aA12B1234567890%0d%0aAB1+1234567890%0d%0aAB++1234567890%0d%0a%0d%0aInvalid%3a+%0d%0aAB1++1234567890%0d%0a+(more+than+4+characters+before+the+numbers)%0d%0aA1B1234567890%0d%0a++(less+than+4+characters+before+the+numbers)%0d%0aA1+B1234567890%0d%0a++(space+amidst+the+first+4+characters+instead+of+at+the+end)&o=m)

If you do not plan to support all Unicode letters, just replace `\p{L}` with `[a-z]` and use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: A slightly more compact alternative: `^[\p{L}\d]((?<!\s)[\p{L}\d]|\s){3}\d{10}\r?$` featuring much less readability :)

Comment: @elgonzo: If I have a choice between a regex yielding the same results with alternation and without it, I'd choose the one without. When tested against `A12B1234567890`, my regex shows 15% faster performance at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) with the one you suggest.

Comment: That's interesting. I just noticed that i did not use a non-capturing group for the alternation - i wonder what fraction of the performance penalty is because of the capturing group, if any at all... I guess i'll test that :) I like your solution more anyway, because it is much easier to "read" from left to right, whereas mine is really not as easy to comprehend :)

Comment: This regex benchmark on regexhero has quite a bit of a temperament (browser environment impact perhaps?). Running the very same benchmark of your regex 20 times i saw performance fluctuations of about 8%. Then, i benchmarked my regex with and without a non-capturing group 20 times each -- the version with the non-capturing group was surprisingly slowest (about 7..8% slower than your regex). My regex with a capturing group was on average only a few percent behind yours, with one benchmark run being even faster than all the runs i did with your regex. I don't know what to make of that...

Answer (score 4):

Here's the regex you need:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9 ]{4}\d{10}$)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4} *\d{10}$
```

It uses a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=    )` to test if it's followed by 4 chars, either alnum or space, and then it goes back to where it was (the beggining of string, not consuming any chars).

Once that condition is met, the rest is a expression quite similar to what you were trying (`[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4} *\d{10}`).

[Online tester](http://rextester.com/tester/WQWQ77979)

Comment: Well, it would also match if there are 10 spaces or so present... :(

Comment: @elgonzo: no. the lookahead `(?=[A-Za-z0-9 ]{4}\d)` makes sure (alnum+ spaces) = 4

Comment: Damn, i missed the `\d` in the look-ahead pattern -- my bad. Your regex seems to be correct... Sorry :)

Comment: This doesn't allow unlimited spaces, but it does allow for there to be too few characters in the prefix.  ABC1234567890 is accepted even though there are less than four characters before the ten digits.

Comment: @jvance: nice catch. I edited the answer to correct it. The lookahead is now `(?=[A-Za-z0-9 ]{4}\d{10}$)`

Comment: @ideafixxxer: it's been corrected right before your comment

Answer (score 2):

I know this is dumb, but must work exactly as required.

```
^[A-Za-z\d]([A-Za-z\d]{3}|[A-Za-z\d]{2}\s|[A-Za-z\d]\s{2}|\s{3})[\d]{10}$
```

Comment: This works, but the look-behind from stribizhev seems more elegant.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are looking for, but perhaps:

```
^(?=.{14}$)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4} *\d{10}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ3uZ3/1)

Comment: This approach clearly shows out-of-the-box thinking! Instead of trying to meet all conditions, you went for the logics behind it. +1

Comment: This is also what I would suggest. Alternatively, the length check can be done outside the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Doesn't allow char/space/char combination and starts with a char:

```
/\b(?!\w\s{1,2}\w+)\w(\w|\s){3}\d{10}/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/fF2tR8/2